# Gson: How to skip specific field

Tags: java, json, gson

I'm trying to parse json object with gson. My json object looks like this.

```
{
  "data": {
    "id": "c33184ce",
    "firstName": "testFirstName",
    "lastName": "testLastName",
  }
}
```

My current class looks like this:

```
public class User {

    private Data data;

    public Data getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(Data data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public class Data {
        private String id;
        // firstName, lastName

        public String getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(String id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        // firstName, lastName setters and getters
    }
}
```

Everything works fine, but when I want to get some User data I have to do it like this:

```
user.getData().getId();
```

Is there some way to parse directly data of user and avoid that data object, so I can access user's id like this?

```
user.getId();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want User class, you can convert your json string to a JsonObject, then get its data object and save the id's in the list or something....

sample code:

```
String json = "your json here";
Gson gson = new Gson();
JsonObject jsonObject = gson.fromJson(json, JsonObject.class);
Data data = gson.fromJson(((JsonObject)jsonObject.get("Data")), Data.class);

System.out.println("Data id:" + data.id);
```